# How can we send parameters separately before the jar in spark submit command with out using extraJavaOptions

Tags: java, apache-spark

We have extraJavaOptions to send the java params in the spark submit. But for some reason the spark job is not able to pick up the java params. So, I am trying to send these java params with out using the `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` and `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions`.

I tried sending the parameters along with the jar, but it did not work

Is there really an another way to send these params. I am using spark 2.3.1 version right now.

This is my original spark command:

```
output=`spark-submit \
    --class com.demo.myApp.App \
    --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dapp.env="$ENV" - 
    Dapp.country="$COUNTRY" -Dapp.year="$YEAR" - 
    Doracle.net.tns_admin=/work/artifacts/oracle/current - 
    Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom' \
    --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dapp.env="$ENV" - 
    Dapp.country="$COUNTRY" -Dapp.year="$YEAR" - 
    Doracle.net.tns_admin=/work/artifacts/oracle/current - 
    Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom' \
    --executor-memory "$EXECUTOR_MEMORY" \
    --executor-cores "$EXECUTOR_CORES" \
    --total-executor-cores "$TOTAL_CORES" \
    --driver-memory "$DRIVER_MEMORY" \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    /home/spark/demo/myApp/current/my-app-*.jar 2>&1 &`
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suggest that you add the `--verbose` flag to `spark-submit` so you can check that your arguments are being correctly populated and parsed by spark.

In your example command, the shell quoting appears to be incorrect (you have double quotes inside single quotes), so variables such as `$ENV` won't be substituted with their values. I normally use plain double quotes, e.g:

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dapp.env=$ENV
        -Dapp.country=$COUNTRY -Dapp.banner=$YEAR" \
```

You don't describe how you are trying to read or check these parameters - it might help if you added this to the question. You could try printing out all of the JVM system properties from within your job code to see if they are arriving as expected.

For parameters that you intend to read directly within your spark code, you can specify them to `spark-submit` in the form:

```
--conf spark.myApp.mySetting=foo \
--conf spark.myApp.anotherSetting=bar \
```

then read them from the `SparkConf` object within your code. However, this won't work for environment variables intended to be read by library code; you will need to get `extraJavaOptions` working for these.

Comment: I have checked the spark launch command on the spark UI and see all the jvm parameters are being passed fine with the expected values. But still it does not work. So, that was the reason I am checking if there is any other way we can pass the jvm parameters with out using extraJavaOptions

Comment: OK, so in what way does it not work? What are you trying to do, what actually happens?

Comment: so when I say it does not work, I mean , I have checks in my source code if the java params are null. Even thought I send the java params in extraJavaOptions, and even when I see my java params are being sent fine in spark launch command, my source code still throws an error stating that the java params are empty

Comment: OK. It might help if you add an example of this checking code to your question.